# Using GroupBy to add new columns to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame  like so

```
id val1 val2
0   A    B
1   C    D
1   E    F
2   G    H
```

and trying to reshape into...

```
id val1 val2 val3 val4
0   A    B
1   C    D    E    F
2   G    H
```

It doesn't matter what the additional column names are and I may not know how many duplicates there are of each id, so I may not know exactly how many columns to add.

Any advice for solving a problem like this?  I've been trying to use pandas and groupBy, but I'm not constrained to either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `pivot` problem, but you'll need to convert your frame from wide to long before you can pivot it:

```
u = df.melt('id')
u.assign(variable=u.groupby('id').cumcount()).pivot(*u)

variable  0  1    2    3
id                      
0         A  B  NaN  NaN
1         C  E    D    F
2         G  H  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't able to quite make it work for my situation, can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @Frankie You've over simplified your problem to the extent that a solution cannot scale. But try this: `df.set_index(['image', df.groupby('image').cumcount()]).unstack()`